# Reasonable to request for pushing out start date again?

Tags: job-offer, new-job, negotiation, start-date

So I have already pushed my start date for a new job by a month previously. I now start in a week, and I’m meeting my potential manager again in a day or so for something else. I’m still okay with the original date if there’s no ability to budge, but I am in need of just a short break in between my current job and new job before I begin. Would it be okay if I ask them to push forward by just a week or would I risk damaging my relationship with my potential manager by asking again and this late?

Comment: Depending on the country and the companies set-up, someone starting on a date other than the 1st or 15th/16th of a month can add a significant amount of work for the payroll.

Answer (score 13):

Two things:

1. They accommodated a change request once
2. You did not calculate properly first time

are reason enough that you should refrain from asking any further extension at this point. It'll reflect on you poorly, not because you want the break, but because it shows you cannot think and plan for future.

Unless there is a very valid reason for the extension (apart from the one for the time-off that you need), I think asking to extend the joining date will most likely backfire, even if you ask and they accept, you'll start with a wrong footing. I'd suggest, start on the date which was decided, and then, after couple of months, plan for a short break to recharge.

Answer (score 1):

To build on another answer, this is likely the first impression you will be making on the relationship with your new manager—an extremely consequential one you will likely be fostering for years to come.

While boundaries are always at least somewhat helpful to probe--such as the tolerance this organization has for short-notice time off--the choice you have in front of you is to weigh the importance of this additional time off versus alienating your manager.

If it were me in the manager's position, an unexpected emergency would certainly justify this, with no hard feelings. But if it's instead an extra week off that you could have easily anticipated earlier, I'd start to worry about how seriously you took your psychological health against the impact it has on your peers.

It's not a completely irreversible perception. To take the other side, if you would be stressed and anxious from still dealing with your previous employer, you would probably do more harm than good coming in without a break. If something like that is the case, please make that clear to your new employer.

But the bottom line is, not giving you the benefit of the doubt, it's a bad look.